# MVC Database Image and Default Image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filecontentresult

have the following image, from a database...

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetLogo", "Logo", new { ID = 16})" />
```

And the controller....

```
public FileContentResult GetLogo(int ID)
{
    var GetImage = (from x in repository.GetClientLogo 
                    where x.ClientID == ClientID
                    select x).FirstOrDefault();

    ClientLogo clientLogo = GetImage;
    return File(clientLogo.ImageData, clientLogo.ImageMimeType);
}
```

This all works fine until there is no database record - if this is the case, then I want to return a default image (example `<img src="../Images/NoLogo.jpg" />`), but I'm having difficulties as the above controller returns `FileContentResult`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
public FileContentResult GetLogo(int ID)
{
    var GetImage = (from x in repository.GetClientLogo
                    where x.ClientID == ClientID
                    select x).FirstOrDefault();
    if (GetImage == null)
    {
      return File(Server.MapPath("/Images/NoLogo.jpg"), "image/jpeg");
    }

    ClientLogo clientLogo = GetImage;
    return File(clientLogo.ImageData, clientLogo.ImageMimeType);
}
```

Just return NoLogo file when you can't find image for client

Comment: Sorry, it's now throwing the error: Cannot convert System.Web.Mvc.FilePathResult to System.Web.Mvc.FileContentResult

Comment: Got it - changed the return type from FileContentResult to ActionResult, then did.... return (ActionResult)File("../Content/Images/General/bigtick.jpg", "image/jpg"); } else { ClientLogo clientLogo = GetImage; return (ActionResult)File(clientLogo.ImageData, clientLogo.ImageMimeType);

Comment: YOu don't need even convert return type to ActionResult, because FileContetntResult and FilePathResult both are descendants of ActionResult